# Python was not found when running pyspark in VSC

Tags: python, apache-spark, visual-studio-code, pyspark

I'm learning `Spark` now and have installed it on a Windows PC.

I used the following guide and to be honest, it all seems right.

Also, when I type in my cmd `spark-shell` it opens `scala`, and when I type `pyspark` in opens the python shell as I would expect.

However, I tried to run the following simple code in Visual Studio Code and I get the following errors:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()

textFile = sc.textFile('example.txt')
print(textFile.count())
```

Error (happens when it reaches `textFile.count()`):

```
Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) (XXX.lan executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
.
.
.
    Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

1. I have had Python installed on my machine for ages and all works well.
2. All Python paths seem to be correct.
3. Added all HADOOP/SPARK paths as mentioned in the guide.
4. Opened the Windows App execution aliases and Python is not even these (App installed python.exe, App installed python3.exe)

Any reason it happens?

**EDIT:**

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

solves the problem but is there a way to solve it temporarily so I wont need to use that in my code?

Comment: Have you choosen the python interpreter